# Does throwing things at enemies deal damage?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

The Tutorial in Deus-Ex: Human Revolution briefly mentions the ability to throw move-able objects at enemies.

Excepting cases where you throw explosives and the like, is there any usefulness in pelting enemies with random crates and miscellanea? Does it deal damage, stun them, or anything other than simply alerting them to your presence?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depends on what you throw, but...yes.

[image: Man in black suit vs dumpster]

Comment: I assume you just "Eliminated the Men in Black Suits" via Dumpster?

Comment: Correct - there's a "Man Down" at the bottom of that.  I'll see if I can't get/find you a video of stuns from thrown objects as well.

Comment: In the future, dumpsters have legs

Comment: Do you know if it is a non-lethal or lethal attack?

Comment: Given that it says "Man Down" but not "Merciful Soul," it's likely lethal.  If it's enough to put them down it's probably enough to kill them...robot arms, and all.

Comment: It's lethal. You can always check whether a body is dead or unconscious by looking at them. There will either be a skull icon if dead or a "Zzz" icon if sleeping. Also, *throwing* items seems to be considered like shooting a weapon by the guard AI.

Comment: **Very** true @Darien - the cops behind that fence were particularly unhappy about flying dumpsters.

Comment: This is the best picture you could use to answer this question.