# Can you kill people by dropping things on their heads?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I know that [throwing things cause damage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28729/does-throwing-things-at-enemies-deal-damage), but if I were to pick up a metal box or a dumpster and drop it from a few stories up onto someone, will it do any damage?

And if it does, does that count against a pacifist play-through?

Comment: I don't know what the answer to this is but consider this, an unconscious person won't die if you drop it on them then (even on their head).

Comment: If the damage from throwing is a result of physics-related, gravity-powered velocity should be just the same. If the damage from throwing only occurs *because* the "throw" button was used, gravity might not matter.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had to test this for myself, and here's the result:

[image: Aiming]

[image: It hit!]

[image: Dead mean]

As you can see, he is clearly dead, so do not try to climb to the top of a building, and throw things down on people! And yes, that would count against the pacifist achievement.

Note: I did it for science!

Comment: So looks like the damage comes from physics, not the actual act of throwing. Nice! Excellent use of pictures!

Comment: Interesting, as for the pacifist achievement, I'm beginning to think that any sort of death in the DEHR universe will cause you to lose it.  I will have to test this further by building a rube goldberg type killing machine!

Comment: @yx_ Maybe try shooting a barrel off a roof and onto someone?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer something along those lines, but involving multiple barrels knocking each other over, I want to be as far removed as the original event as possible and I have to test this on the last mission(or at the nearest feasible point to the end) so I can test to see if it cost me the pacifist achievement.  It will take a while to set up.

Comment: @yx_ Well, if you find an enemy worth XP you can see if you get the Man Down bonus from their death. Doesn't apply to hobos, obviously, but "got xp for killing them" is a pretty dead giveaway of "no longer a pacifist"

Comment: @Raven Except, apparently, [snapping someone's just a little bit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28609/how-can-i-not-snap-peoples-necks-or-only-snap-it-a-little-bit/30260#30260) is a lethal takedown that gets you Man Down but it does not count against Pacifist.

Comment: @Grace - the difference being that the latter is scripted, but this is not.

Comment: @Raven I have a hard time imagining a Rube Goldberg Killing Machine as anything *but* "scripted" ♪